# getting strange results from my xml (de)serializer

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I have created a streamExtension where i can simply serialize and deserialze the stream from and to an xml file, the code looks as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// Contains the logic for streaming extensions.
/// </summary>
public static class StreamExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Serialize an object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the object that gets serialized.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="stream">The stream to which the bytes will be written.</param>
    /// <param name="serializableObject">The object that gets serialized.</param>
    public static void SerializeObject<T>(this Stream stream, T serializableObject) where T : IXmlSerializable
    {
        var xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
        xmlTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        xmlTextWriter.IndentChar = ' ';
        xmlTextWriter.Indentation = 4;

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        serializer.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, serializableObject);

        xmlTextWriter.Close();
        stream.Close();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deserialize a stream and return the object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the object that returns from the deserialization.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="stream">The stream which contains the bytes to deserialize.</param>
    /// <returns>The object recovered.</returns>
    public static T DeserializeObject<T>(this Stream stream)
    {
        var xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        var result = (T)serializer.Deserialize(xmlTextReader);

        xmlTextReader.Close();
        stream.Close();

        return result;
    }
}
```

2 very simple (and if I may say so: elegant) methods for serializing and deserializing.

I am using this class as a test:

```
/// <summary>
/// A serializable class for testing purposes.
/// </summary>
public class SerializableXmlTest : IXmlSerializable
{
    #region Fields
    private string mTestString = string.Empty;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the configuration for this simulation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The configuration for this simulation.</value>
    public string TestString
    {
        get
        {
            return mTestString;
        }

        set
        {
            mTestString = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region XML serialization region
    /// <summary>
    /// Write the extra information to an XML stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="writer">Writer to write to.</param>
    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name);
        writer.WriteAttributeString("TestString", this.TestString);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Read the extra information from an XML stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="reader">Reader to read from.</param>
    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        if ((reader.MoveToContent() == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name))
        {
            reader.Read();
            this.TestString = reader.GetAttribute("TestString");
        }

        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is reserved when implementing the IXmlSerializable interface.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>An XmlSchema that describes the XML representation of the
    /// object that is produced by the WriteXml method and consumed by the
    /// ReadXml method.</returns>
    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

And this is the code in my unit test:

```
/// <summary>
/// Test the stream extension class for normal function.
/// </summary>
[Test]
public void TestStreamExtension()
{
    File.Delete(mFileName);
    var testObject = new SerializableXmlTest();
    testObject.TestString = "Test";

    Stream saveFileStream = new FileStream(mFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    saveFileStream.SerializeObject(testObject);

    Stream openFileStream = new FileStream(mFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    var testObjectClone = openFileStream.DeserializeObject<SerializableXmlTest>();
    Assert.IsTrue(testObject.TestString.Equals(testObjectClone.TestString));
    }
```

And the xml file that is ouputted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SerializableXmlTest>
    <SerializableXmlTest TestString="Test" />
</SerializableXmlTest>
```

However there are a few things i don't understand and at least one of them is definitely wrong (I think)

The first thing is I expected my xml file to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SerializableXmlTest TestString="Test" />
```

But I can understand if you need the separate start and end element.

The second thig when trying to read It the first element the reader lands on is (as expected) `<SerializableXmlTest>` However if I then proceed to do a `reader.Read()` or `reader.ReadStartElement()` the debugger tells me it is currently reading:

```
{Whitespace, Value="\r\n    "}.
```

Where does this come from? why is it reading a new line character? Obviously when i then use an other `reader.Read()` i do get to the `<SerializableXmlTest TestString="Test" />` line in my xml file.

What am I doing wrong?

P.s.
It might be wise to tell you i changed the serialize and deserialze methods a bit, (they used to be working) but the serialize used only the xmlTextWriter and not the XmlSerializer. and the Deserialize method used a stream reader instead of XmlTextReader. but for the sake of trying to make them the same i got this problem which i can't seem to figure out.

Extra question: should I even use the XmlTextReader and writer? I could just as well pass the stream I get as method parameter to the serializer couldn't I?

Comment: Side note: using `using` would make your serialization helpers not only elegant but also correct (and match everyone else implementation).

Comment: Thanks, changed it :)

Comment: Don't use `XmlTextWriter`/`XmlTextReader` classes. Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0 recommends use the `XmlWriter`/`XmlReader` instead. Use `XmlWriterSettings`/`XmlReaderSettings` to configure them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things.

1) The failure with the serializer

```
XmlSerializer.Serialize(stream, object)
```

already writes the encoding of the file and the start element. That's why you get the strange output. Reduce your `WriteXML` method to just open the stream, and let the serializer do the rest. That will fix your written XML file.

2) The read of `\r\n`

There are currently 2 ways to access XML data in .NET

- `XmlReader \ XmlWriter`
- `XmlFile`

When you use the `XmlReader` you will have way more access to a XML file and way more deep. That means on the other hand, that some automations get lost. The `XmlReader.Read()` works completely correct. First he finds an `<` sign. So now he knows to read till he finds `>` an end tag. Then u tell him to read again. Now he reads an `\r\n` sign. Now he knows that he has to stop, because you told him to read only 1 character and he didn't found `<` a beginning tag.

Hope this helps

Comment: Is there a way to make Serialize not write the start and end element but do it my self?

Comment: I know that u can create ur own mappings and then create out of them a serializer. But I think this will not change, that the serializer will write all needed for a valid xml file. What is actually the reason for the need to not let the serializer handle that? maybe there is a better solution

Comment: Because I also use abstract classes and you either need those [] tags above a list of abstract classes to indicate which classes there are or you need to read/write the xml your self. the company decided against the tags because that would mean, every time you create a new derived class you need to open the abstract class and add a tag there. The less we need to open and change old files the better.

Comment: Sr but for this point, I currently have no answer. Maybe it is possible to teach the serializer this behavior, but from my point of view, I would go another way. I would take the serializer, write a class with it using the serializer and manipulate the file/stream afterwards to my needs.

Comment: Or maybe not use xmlSerializer but just the xmlTextReader and writer.